# LoadError: InitError: While Precompiling in new Environment

Tags: julia

I wanted to start using dedicated environments for all my julia projects, but activating the new environment and using packages (eg. Plots.jl) results in Precompiling that fails with the following error:

```
 Activating environment at `~/Documents/baro/Project.toml`

julia> using Plots
[ Info: Precompiling Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80]
ERROR: LoadError: InitError: could not load library "/home/marius/.julia/artifacts/08ab4b2de494e1d61e581ab1fbd610b0b4d1876f/lib/libavdevice.so"
libx264.so.157: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Stacktrace:
 [1] dlopen(::String, ::UInt32; throw_error::Bool) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Libdl/src/Libdl.jl:109
 [2] dlopen at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Libdl/src/Libdl.jl:109 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [3] __init__() at /home/marius/.julia/packages/FFMPEG_jll/tCUYA/src/wrappers/x86_64-linux-gnu.jl:231
 [4] _include_from_serialized(::String, ::Array{Any,1}) at ./loading.jl:697
 [5] _require_search_from_serialized(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:781
 [6] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:1006
 [7] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:927
 [8] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:922
 [9] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:377
 [10] top-level scope at none:2
 [11] eval at ./boot.jl:331 [inlined]
 [12] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:449
 [13] top-level scope at ./none:3
during initialization of module FFMPEG_jll
in expression starting at /home/marius/.julia/packages/FFMPEG/vocw2/src/FFMPEG.jl:3
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile FFMPEG [c87230d0-a227-11e9-1b43-d7ebe4e7570a] to /home/marius/.julia/compiled/v1.4/FFMPEG/TGvga_eB360.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1272
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:1029
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:927
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:922
 [6] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:377
 [7] top-level scope at none:2
 [8] eval at ./boot.jl:331 [inlined]
 [9] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:449
 [10] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /home/marius/.julia/packages/Plots/LWw1t/src/Plots.jl:15
ERROR: Failed to precompile Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80] to /home/marius/.julia/compiled/v1.4/Plots/ld3vC_eB360.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1272
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:1029
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:927
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:922
```

This also happens for some other packages like ControlSystems.
The julia version is 1.4.2 but I was able to reproduce this error with 1.5.0 and on a different computer with 1.3.1 on it. Both systems are runnning Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

What I tried so far was:

- Rebuilding the package `Pkg.build()`
- Check that the file supposed to load exists (it existed)
- Update libx264
- Deleting all packages in .julia folder and and reinstalling everything using `Pkg.instantiate()`

Any help to get the packages running will be greatly appreciated as I really like the idea of having dedicated environments for every project. Also on 1.3.1 even after switching to the default environment the error is still occuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to lay in the FFMPEG package.
The following solved the issue for me:
Remove FFMPEG. Then delete the folder which is given in the error message. In your case: `"/home/marius/.julia/artifacts/08ab4b2de494e1d61e581ab1fbd610b0b4d1876f/lib/libavdevice.so"`
Then add FFPEG again which results in a change in the Manifest.toml which does not happen if you just remove FFMPEG:

```
Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.3/Manifest.toml`
  [1270edf5] ↓ x264_jll v2020.7.14+0 ⇒ v2019.5.25+2
```

Try: `using FFMPEG, Plots`.
I was able to precompile Plots then.

Comment: The Precompile finishes successfully now, thank you very much!

Comment: thanks, if you encounter a similar problem with other packages, you can use this method to solve it, which is not limited to the specified package, for example it works with pkg `MKL`.

Comment: It really works!